# Content Builder Landingpage custom Layout

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage

Is there an option to add a custom layout for Content Builder landingpages? Our requirement is to use 100% width (Responsive) which no of the default templates supports. Currently we use the default one, and overwrite the HTML Code, but that isn't really comfortable.

[image]

Comment: Have you looked at CloudPages?  https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/cloudpages/

Comment: Yes. But as far as I understand. You have to select one of the base templates (screenshot above) and based on that template you can build, whatever you want. But I can't find a way to modify/create new base templates.

Comment: You could use the 'Classic Editor' but that has it's own drawbacks.   I don't see any options when it comes to customizing your base layer (other than what you're doing).

Comment: Same problem I am facing, trying to do the same thing https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/192133/how-to-create-a-template-in-cloudpages